# Sort list of Person based on Birthday from current date python?

Tags: python, sorting, date

I have a List of Person Object with attribute name and DOB(date of birth)

```
[{'name':'robert', 'DOB':'1991-12-17'},
 {'name':'Alex', 'DOB':'1995-1-31'}, 
 {'name':'Julia','DOB':'1993-4-20'},
 {'name':'sevak', 'DOB':'1991-12-17'}, 
 {'name':'feb', 'DOB':'1991-03-07'}]
```

Note : DOB is in string format only.

I am trying to sort this list in python based on the most recent upcoming birthday from current Date.

My expected output's:

if current date is 2017-05-21, then the output should be as follows:

```
[{'name':'robert', 'DOB':'1991-12-17'},
 {'name':'sevak', 'DOB':'1991-12-18'},
 {'name':'Alex', 'DOB':'1995-1-31'},
 {'name':'feb', 'DOB':'1991-03-07'},
 {'name':'Julia','DOB':'1993-4-20'}]
```

if current date is 2017-03-14, then the output should be as follows:

```
[{'name':'Julia','DOB':'1993-4-20'},
 {'name':'robert', 'DOB':'1991-12-17'},
 {'name':'sevak', 'DOB':'1991-12-18'},
 {'name':'Alex', 'DOB':'1995-1-31'},
 {'name':'feb', 'DOB':'1991-03-07'}]
```

Note: Ignore the year for this sorting I need to sort based on most recent upcoming birthday's that are gonna show up

This is what I have tried so far:

```
for each_patient in patientlist: 
    globaldata.patients_records[str(each_patient['id'])] = each_patient; 
    x = each_patient['date_of_birth']; 
    if not x == None: 
    x = add_months(datetime.datetime(*[int(item) for item in x.split('-')]), 1).strftime("%Y-%m-%d"); 
    print x; 
    each_patient['date_of_birth'] = x; 
    patients.append(each_patient); 
patients_url = data['next']; 
patients.sort(key=lambda ep: ep['date_of_birth']);
```

Thanks in advance guyzz..

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Comment: for each_patient in patientlist:
            globaldata.patients_records[str(each_patient['id'])] = each_patient;
            x = each_patient['date_of_birth'];
            if not x == None:
                x = add_months(datetime.datetime(*[int(item) for item in x.split('-')]), 1).strftime("%Y-%m-%d");
                print x;
            each_patient['date_of_birth'] = x;
            patients.append(each_patient);
        patients_url = data['next'];
patients.sort(key=lambda ep: ep['date_of_birth']);

Comment: This is a pretty decent question. dont down vote if you can't do it.... in whole stack overflow no one as asked such question.

Comment: The downvotes originated from not having shown any effort in the original post. Since you have now shown some attempts I have retracted by down vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert these strings to `datetime` object and use `sorted()` to sort by date from today's date:

```
l = [{'name': 'robert', 'DOB': '1991-12-17'},
     {'name': 'Alex', 'DOB': '1995-1-31'},
     {'name': 'Julia', 'DOB': '1993-4-20'},
     {'name': 'sevak', 'DOB': '1991-12-17'},
     {'name': 'feb', 'DOB': '1991-03-07'}]

from datetime import datetime as dt

now = dt.strptime("2017-03-14", '%Y-%m-%d')
# now=dt.now()
sorted(l, key=lambda x: (dt.strptime(str(now.year + 1) + x["DOB"][4:], '%Y-%m-%d') - now).days % 365)
```

Result:

```
[{'DOB': '1993-4-20', 'name': 'Julia'},
{'DOB': '1991-12-17', 'name': 'robert'},
{'DOB': '1991-12-17', 'name': 'sevak'},
{'DOB': '1995-1-31', 'name': 'Alex'},
{'DOB': '1991-03-07', 'name': 'feb'}]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot thats working exactly the way i wanted it .. :)